# Python libinsane in Windows

Tags: python, windows, gobject, twain, image-scanner

I'm currently trying to have libinsane working on python (2.7 or 3.4) on Windows 10.

Following instruction from official doc (https://doc.openpaper.work/libinsane/latest/libinsane/install.html), I've successfully build a 64b version.

But, I'm not familiar with GObject, I don't know where to put DLL and typelib files!

Anyone can help me to understand how to have libinsane working?

At this time, I'm just trying to have the official examples working. (https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/libinsane/tree/master/subprojects/libinsane-gobject/examples)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can maybe use ProcMon to see where your process is trying to look for those files.

Answer (score 3):

I have been able to make the examples to work and here is how.

First of all, make sure you have [mysys2](https://www.msys2.org/) installed.

Follow the installation instructions in the link above.

Following that, run this mingw64.exe in *C:\msys64*

run the following commands from the installation guide.

```
pacman -S \
    make \
    mingw-w64-x86_64-cunit \
    mingw-w64-x86_64-doxygen \
    mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc \
    mingw-w64-x86_64-gobject-introspection \
    mingw-w64-x86_64-meson \
    mingw-w64-x86_64-python3-gobject \
    mingw-w64-x86_64-vala
```

Then run this:

```
 git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/OpenPaperwork/libinsane.git
cd libinsane

make PREFIX=/mingw64
```

and finally

```
make install
```

The latter 2 commands must be run inside the libinsane directory.
You can the navigation to the example sample projects and run:

```
python list_device.py
```

for listing devices

```
python scan.py outputfilename.png
```

for scanning documents

**DLL Files**
In development, you wont need to package the dll files but in production, for any other language other than windows, it will be a requirement.

Unfortunately, they didn't state where to put them. I have opened an issue for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using ProcMon as you suggested has helped to solve my problem, it now works fine!

In case this can help anyone to make libinsane working on Python, you need to put these DLLs at these places:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libsystre-0.dll => <python path>/lib/site-packages/gnome
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libtre-5.dll => <python path>/lib/site-packages/gnome
C:\msys64\usr\local\lib\girepository-1.0\Libinsane-1.0.typelib => <python path>/lib/site-packages/gnome/lib/girepository-1.0/
C:\msys64\usr\local\bin\libinsane_gobject.dll => <python path>/lib/site-packages/gnome
C:\msys64\usr\local\bin\libinsane.dll => <python path>/lib/site-packages/gnome
```